# Найти количество целых решений, удовлетворяющих неравенству: A ≤ B*x + C ≤ D

Tags: олимпиада

Формат ввода

В единственной строке заданы четыре целых числа:ъ

A, B, C и D (0 ≤ A, B, C, D ≤ 10**18, B ≠ 0).

Формат вывода

Выведите одно число – количество целых решений данного неравенства.

Пример 1

Ввод
1 1 0 5

Вывод

5

Пример 2

Ввод

46 7 108 37
Вывод
0

Comment: Что именно у Вас не получается?

Comment: @sorevoxer,  Если Вас устраивает ответ - отметьте его галочкой слева, если нет - скажите, что не так.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов не получается написать это в виде кода, не знаю нужны ли файлы для input или нет

Comment: к сожалению, Вы не указали язык, на котором решаете задачу, так что пока я не знаю, смогу ли что-то еще Вам подсказать. Что касается файлов для ввода, так это смотря откуда вводить. Если из файла - то нужны. А сохранять введенное в файл... А зачем?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов это олимпиадная задача и можно выбрать любой язык для её решения, python, c, c++, Pascal и тд

Comment: Вам тоже все равно, на каком языке писать?

Comment: прошу прощения за опечатки в нике...

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов единственная задача для меня - это решить, найти решение и скопипастить или как-то додумать самому, что для меня большая проблема, к сожалению

Comment: что именно не получается додумать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика элементарная:

1. Ищем корень уравнения A = B*x + C.
2. Берем x1 как ближайшее сверху целое от найденного корня.
3. Ищем корень уравнения D = B*x + C.
4. Берем x2 как ближайшее снизу целое от найденного корня.
5. Находим количество целых чисел от x1 до x2 включительно. Это и есть ответ.